# Namespace issues in C++ when friend function is defined outside class body

Tags: c++

Why operator<< for Test struct do not work when defined outside struct body?

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

namespace my::time
{

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time)
{
    stream << "...";
    return stream;
}

} // namespace my::time

namespace other_namespace::nested
{

struct Test
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point _timePoint;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t1);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t1)
{
    using namespace my::time;
    os << t1._timePoint; // <------ here is problem
     return os;

}

}


int main()
{
    other_namespace::nested::Test t;
    t._timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt link to example](https://godbolt.org/z/6a7KexcGf)

Issue:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point' (aka 'const time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, duration<long, ratio<1, 1000000000>>>'))
```

But there is no issue when I define same operator like this:

```cpp
struct Test
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point _timePoint;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t1)
    {
        using namespace my::time;
        os << t1._timePoint;
        return os;
    }
};
```

PS. I know that in newer C++ stdlib there is implementation for such operator<< but I would like to use my own.

Build using: clang 16 with -std=c++20
libstdc++ version: 20220924, _GLIBCXX_RELEASE:12
Using [Alpine Linux 18.03](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libstdc%2B%2B%2A&branch=v3.18&repo=&arch=&maintainer=)

PS2. When using newer compiler it will compile but it will use std::chrono implementation not mine. So example output would be:

```cpp
std::cout << t << std::endl; // 2023-10-14 08:18:53.841272299
```

Instead: "..."

Comment: @Jason why you waste time if you don't want read and understand my question. Issue here is that in older cimpiler/stdlib there is no std::chrono::operator<< implemented. But my intention is to use my own operator<< for time_point. In newer version like clang17 it will compile but return bad result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a friend function defined in a class is not found by a normal unqualified lookup, *including from within the function itself*. Whereas a function defined outside of a class is found, and that stops any further lookup.

Here is a minimalistic demo:

```
struct Foo
{
};

namespace FooImpl
{
    void doit(Foo) {}
}

namespace BarImpl
{
    struct Bar
    {
        friend void doit(Bar);
    };

    void doit(Bar) { 
        using namespace FooImpl;
        doit(Foo{});
    }
}
```

The error message is straightforward:

```
moo.cpp: In function ‘void BarImpl::doit(Bar)’:
moo.cpp:21:14: error: could not convert ‘Foo()’ from ‘Foo’ to ‘BarImpl::Bar’
```

So you can see that the unqualified lookup for `doit` finds `BarImpl::doit` and stops. `FooImpl` is not even considered because unqualified lookup doesn't propagate outwards once a name is found.

Rename `BarImpl::doit(Bar)` to `BarImpl::dothat(Bar)`, and the lookup suddenly finds `FooImpl::doit`, like magic.

Comment: If I understand correctly on your example. This isn't compiling because compiler already found other operator<< overload and simply do not try to find other ? Even if this overload do not match?

Comment: Yes that's how lookup generally works. It stops at the first scope that has the name, and then checks all the overloaded names in that scope. If none match, it's an error and outer scopes are not checked.

Comment: Thank you, over all after reading your answer more than 10 times I understand. I didn't focus on part: "including from within the function itself". Now I more understand your example and my case why it works when defined "inline body of struct". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to achieve what you want(which is to *provide the definition of the friend function outside the struct*) is to use [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) instead of **using directive** as shown below.

Note the use of `using my::time::operator<<` instead of `using namespace my::time`.

```
struct Test
{
    //other code as before
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t1);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t1)
{
    using my::time::operator<<;  //changed this to using declaration instead of using directive
    os << t1._timePoint; //      works now
    
    return os;
}

}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEYbjMKr7)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I wanted to know why defined "in line" operator works and why defined outside doesn't. Overall your solution with using I was already aware.

Comment: @Gelldur I see. Since the solution that I presented wasn't mentioned in the original question(and so I had no way of knowing that you knew the workaround), I thought that i should write it as an answer so that future readers who don't know that answer/workaround can use it.